# UI Datepicker not opening

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am very new with **UI Bootstrap** for **AngularJS**. I am trying to use the [datepicker](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) but it does not open.

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sFIJSzuuFUk3uh8MZ8he?p=preview)

**Scripts:**

```
<script src="../Scripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.min.js"></script>
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angular").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/angular.js",
                    "~/Script/angular-route.js"));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstrap").Include(
                    "~/Content/bootrap.css",
                    "~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inject $timeout into your controller.

change open() to:

```
 $scope.open = function () {

  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.opened = true;  
  });

};
```

and change data-is-open to:

```
data-is-open="opened"
```

[**see it working here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/m3Pzh7kxmkx6lGYVLdoP?p=preview)

Comment: don't forget to inject it into your controller:
function DatepickerDemoCtrl($scope, $timeout) {

Comment: still does not work, will edit question to show scripts I am using. Maybe I am missing something

Comment: please see it working in the plunk at the bottom of my answer.  tested in firefox 26, chrome 33, safari 7 and IE 11

Comment: I saw that the plunker works but for some strange reason it does not work in my solution

Comment: I am not familiar with the way you are including angular and bootstrap... however, it looks like you are including them after including the ui-bootstrap.min.js. Since ui-bootstrap depends on both angular and bootstrap, you need to make sure you are including it after both of them. so: 

<script src="path to bootstrap"></script>
<script src="path to angular"></script>
<script src="path to ui-bootstrap"></script>

Comment: I made sure it is as you describe but still does not work. I put an alert before $scope.opened = true; and the alert display but no datepicker

Comment: It was a script issue. Thanks for assisting

Answer (score 0):

@xyclos provided a great answer that was very insightful but when it is used with a repeated template it causes ***ALL*** the [datepicker](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker)'s on the page to open at the same time.

This is because it is tying all the datepicker's to the single scope variable "open".

This made me realize that the samples page for UI Bootstrap has exactly the same problem. I was able to fix this problem with highlighted changes below (Which I believe is even more straightforward anyway).

```html
<div ng-repeat="surgery in surgeries">
    <label>SurgeryDate</label>
    <p class="input-group">
        <input type="text" 
             is-open="surgery.open"               class="form-control" 
               uib-datepicker-popup="yyyy-MM-dd" 
               ng-model="surgery.SurgeryDate" 
        />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" 
                ng-click="surgery.open = true"                    class="btn btn-default">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
            </button>
        </span>
    </p>
</div>
```